# How to recreate a Firebase Firestore Database, using test mode instead of locked mode

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I accidentally chose locked mode when creating a Firebase Firestore database, and I can't find a way to change it or delete the database.

I've looked around the internet and haven't found anything that helps me.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The mode selection just determines what your security rules initially look like.  It's not a persistent setting.  Rules are meant to change over time to suit the security needs of your app.  Rules can be see in the rules tab of the Firestore console.

If you're suggesting that you don't want to restrict all reads and writes to only authenticated users, as is the case if you initially choose locked mode, then all you have to do is update your rules to be what you actually want.  All test mode does is initially set your rules so that everyone has full control over the database (which is normally a very bad idea).  But if you need that, you can simply set the initial rule to `allow read, write;`